# Navigation bar keeps turning into gray despite changing it to white. Why?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uicolor

I'm using this code to turn the "Back" button on a navigation bar to white, but it keeps making it gray.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

I also tried this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xFFFFFF)];
```

I've also tried (I found it in another question):

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0]];
```

None of them work! They keep making it gray! If I try red/black/green or another color, they work, but white keeps turning into gray.

Comment: Have you put this in your app delegate?

Comment: @JeevanThandi That is where it's located

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this...

```
UINavigationController *controller= [[UINavigationController alloc]     
initWithRootViewController:YourViewController];
controller.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

Comment: it tells me that rootController is undeclared.

Comment: rootController is the instance of your first view controller.

Comment: How do I know it's name? I've gone to my storyboards and placed the view controllers names but they don't work. Or am I looking at the wrong location?

Comment: I just realised, are you trying to change the back button colour or the navigation bar colour?

Comment: Have you tried changing it in your .storyboard file